# EXC_BAD_ACCESS in stack implementaton

Tags: c, xcode, xcode5, exc-bad-access

I'm trying to write a program to check for balanced parentheses, but when I try to initialize the stack/array I get a bad access (code=1, address 0x0).

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define TRUE 1
#define FALSE 0

#define MAX_STRING_LEN 1000
#define MAX_STACK_SIZE 5000

typedef char StackElement;

typedef struct Stack{
    StackElement *content;
    int maxSize;
    int top;
}Stack;


void Init(Stack*stack);
void Destroy(Stack*stack);
void Push(Stack*stack, StackElement element);
StackElement Pop(Stack*stack);  
int IsEmpty(Stack*stack);
int IsFull(Stack*stack);



/*
 * A new stack variable is initialized.  The initialized
 * stack is made empty. MaxSize is used to determine the
 * maximum number of character that can be held in the
 * stack.
 */
void Init(Stack *stack)
{
    StackElement *newContent;

    /* Allocate a new array to hold the content.*/
    newContent = (StackElement*)malloc(sizeof(StackElement)* MAX_STACK_SIZE);

    if (newContent == NULL) {
        printf("Insufficient memory to initialize stack.\n");
        exit(1);/* Exit, returning error code.*/
    }

    stack->content = newContent;
    stack->maxSize = MAX_STACK_SIZE;
    stack->top = -1;
}

int CheckBalancedParentheses (char* expression){
    int i = 0;
    Stack *stack;
    Init(stack);

    if (strcmp(&expression[i], ")") == 0 || strcmp(&expression[i], "]") == 0 || strcmp(&expression[i], "}") == 0){
        return FALSE;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < strlen(expression); i++){
        if (strcmp(&expression[i], "(") == 0 || strcmp(&expression[i], "[") == 0 || strcmp(&expression[i], "{") == 0){
            Push(stack, expression[i]);
        }
    }

    return TRUE;
}
```

The bad access is happening on all of these lines (I tested them individually):

```
stack->content = newContent;
stack->maxSize = MAX_STACK_SIZE;
stack->top = -1;
```

I can't figure out why it's giving me a bad access, any help/advice would be appreciated!

Thank you in advanced.

Comment: `stack->content` : `stack` is NULL.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY `stack` is _uninitialized_.

Comment: @AlexD It is unconfirmed.

Comment: I'm trying to initialize it using Init and I declared it with Stack *stack. The Init function is initializing it, or at least I thought.

Comment: @PM try `Stack stack;Init(&stack);` or `Stack *stack=malloc(sizeof(*stack));Init(stack);`

Comment: athese two lines: Stack *stack;
    Init(stack); are declaring a pointer the points to trash then passing that pointer to Init().  A better method would be Stack stack; Init( &stack );

Answer (score 1):

You have defined a stack pointer, this does not allocate memory.

You need a malloc statement in CheckBalancedParentheses before you call Init:

```
/* Allocate memory for our stack */
Stack* stack = malloc( sizeOf(Stack) );
```